# Quicksort Median of Three

Tags: java, sorting

I'm working on my Quick Sort exercise that uses a LinkedList to sort, (I know it's not efficient and really pointless, it's for class). I understand how the Quick Sort method works, as well as the median of three strategy. My code is working properly for only certain lengths however, for example.

---

This works fine:

`7 6 5 4 3 2 1`, pivot = 4

`7 6 5`, pivot = 6 | `3 2 1`, pivot  = 2

---

Now, for anything that isn't like that, ie.

`5 4 3 2 1`, pivot = 3

`5 4`, throws an error | `2 1` throws an error.

---

Here is the code that I have:

---

Finds the middle node in the LinkedList.

```
public Node findMiddleNode() {
    Node node1 = first;
    Node node2 = first;
    while(node2.getNext() != null && node2.getNext().getNext()!= null) {
        node1 = node1.getNext();
        node2 = node2.getNext().getNext();
    }
    return node1;
}
```

---

Finds the median of the first, middle and last nodes.

```
public Node medianOfThree() {
    Node firstNode = first;
    Node lastNode = last;
    Node middleNode = findMiddleNode();

    if((firstNode.getData() - middleNode.getData()) * (lastNode.getData() - firstNode.getData()) >= 0) {
        return firstNode;
    } else if((middleNode.getData() - firstNode.getData()) * (lastNode.getData() - middleNode.getData()) >= 0) {
        return middleNode;
    } else {
        return lastNode;
    }
}
```

---

Removes the pivots from the list, this is the method which breaks.

```
private Node chooseAndRemovePivot() {
    Node pivot = medianOfThree();
    Node previous = first;

    // If the pivot is the first Node.
    if(previous == pivot) {
        first = previous.getNext();
    }

    // Gets the last Node before the pivot
    while(previous.getNext() != pivot) {
        previous = previous.getNext();
    }

    previous.setNext(pivot.getNext());
    pivot.setNext(null);
    size--;
    if (size == 0)
        last = null;
    return pivot;
}
```

Can anyone point out what's going wrong here, I'm sure it's a simple mistake that I am making.

**EDIT: Solution;**

In the method chooseAndRemovePivot();

```
// If the pivot is the first Node.
if(previous == pivot) {
    first = previous.getNext();
} else {
    // Gets the last Node before the pivot
    while(previous.getNext() != pivot) {
        previous = previous.getNext();
    }
}
```

This gets it working for all lengths.

Comment: What about the exception stack trace? That is of course the most useful part of debugging most errors.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to use my debugger, I've usually just manual done it. I am getting a NullPointerException on the line `while(previous.getNext() != pivot)`, I'll look up quickly how to use the debugger properly and update the post with more information.

Comment: That was incredibly useful. The only thing that can cause an NPE on that line is if `previous == null`, thus the cause is much easier to discover since we now know the erroneous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `medianOfThree` function will return `pivot == first` for lists of length 2. Thus this code:

```
// Gets the last Node before the pivot
while(previous.getNext() != pivot) {
    previous = previous.getNext();
}
```

...will never find the terminal condition and instead assign `previous = null` when it reaches the end of the list. Then the next iteration will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this until now. I got the code to work properly now, I'll update the original post with a solution for anyone who may have a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the error is in your findMiddleNode() function.  Specifically, node2.getNext.getNext() doesn't ever check that node2.getNext() is not null

in a list with an even number of items, node2.getNext().getNext() will run off the end. effectively reducing the statement to Null.getNext() which is an error.

For example using the list

```
first -> a -> b -> null
```

1. First node1 and node2 are set to "first.
2. Then node1 becomes a, and node2 becomes b.
3. Then node1 becomes b and node2 becomes b.getNext().getNext() or in other words Null.getNext.

The algorithm works for odd length lists, because node2.getNext().getNext() will always land on the null